# Insert into a cell the first five characters of the filename

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, filenames, worksheet-function

I know the formula for inserting the filename, however the file is e.g `54321 Cost Data` and I just require to insert the `54321`.

Is it possible to insert into a cell the first five characters of the filename?

Comment: You just need a substring function, `Left()` seems a good catch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))+1,5)
```

.

---

@barry houdini has kindly pointed out that the above is flawed (in a way that may not often be an issue but could at times be very confusing):

> It's better to use a cell reference in CELL function with this formula, e.g. `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,5)` - that ensures that the filename used in the formula is the same as the filename where the sheet resides. If you don't do that, and you go in to another workbook and change a cell in that workbook your formula may return a different result, i.e. based on the name of the 2nd workbook.

The syntax for [CELL](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/CELL-function-b98b713d-d3de-4148-829f-80c886af6410?CorrelationId=ad182447-2b7c-4d12-a59f-d51c47ce680c&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) is:

```
 CELL(info_type, [reference])
```

> **reference**    Optional. The cell that you want information about. If omitted, the information specified in the ***info_type*** argument is returned for the last cell that was changed.

So 'my' formula should work when first placed in a cell. Might still be working when that cell is next viewed. All *seems* in order - until the day the displayed value is different and not as a result of any change to the workbook the cell is in. Such behaviour is not what I would describe as 'conventional' for Excel. Even if the last cell that was changed was in a different workbook the cell giving me the value I expect for *this* workbook may change what is displays.

So better to 'play safe', do as @barry suggests (as always!) and add the 'optional' reference.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd knew it would be simple but couldn't find anything about it

Comment: @pnuts - It's better to use a cell reference in `CELL` function with this formula, e.g. `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,5)` - that ensures that the filename used in the formula is the same as the filename where the sheet resides. If you don't do that, and you go in to another workbook and change a cell in that workbook your formula may return a different result, i.e. based on the name of the 2nd workbook

Comment: @pnuts - I'm quite happy for you to edit accordingly - help file for CELL function explains how it works if reference is omitted